# Update to java-8, Maven restore jre to old version in eclipse kepler

Tags: java-8, maven-3, eclipse-kepler

I'm trying to upgrade to Java 8.
I'm using Eclipse kepler an maven for my java projects.

Did the following:

- Installed jdk 8.
- Changed my JAVA_HOME system variable to point the new jdk.
- In my Eclipse Kepler I installed:

[Eclipse Java 8 Support For Kepler](https://wiki.eclipse.org/JDT/Eclipse_Java_8_Support_For_Kepler)

[Java 8 Facet for Web Tools for Eclipse Kepler SR2](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/java-8-facet-web-tools-eclipse-kepler-sr2)

[Java™ 8 support for m2e for Eclipse Kepler SR2](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/java%E2%84%A2-8-support-m2e-eclipse-kepler)

Then for each of my projects I made sure to update project facets, java compiler and jre (in java build path) to version 1.8.

also changed in each pom.xml the java version to 1.8.

The problem occurs when I do maven-->update project, this causes the project facets, compiler and jre settings to jump to 1.4 for some reason.

I can then manually (again) change those back to 1.8 and everything is fine but every time I update a maven dependency or run maven-->update project I encounter the issue again.

Any suggestions?

Comment: using most up-to-date m2e version?

Comment: Can you post your pom.xml?

Comment: Eventually updated to Luna to resolve the issue..

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I have

[Java 8 support for Eclipse Kepler SR2 ]

[Eclipse Java 8 Support (for Kepler SR2) JDT, PDE](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-java-8-support-kepler-sr2-jdt-pde)

[Java™ 8 support for m2e for Eclipse Kepler SR2](https://wiki.eclipse.org/JDT/Eclipse_Java_8_Support_For_Kepler)

installed.

in Eclipse go to **Help -> Eclipse Marketplace...**,
go to the Install tab and **Update** those three (or uninstall and install again).

I also have 1.8 in pom.xml and it works when using Maven -> Update Project